# How to use a combination of integer indices and an array as indices for a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
x = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6, 7],
            [8, 9, 10, 11]])
x = np.array([np.array(x), np.array(x), np.array(x)])
arr = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
print(x[:, arr])
```

I need (:, 1, 1) and (:, 2, 2) of that array

That is:

```
[5, 5, 5]
[10, 10, 10]
```

But it is returning (:, 1) and (:, 2) twice
I've tried using tuple as well.

Edit: using x[(slice(None), *zip(*arr))] worked. But what if i need to use ':' in between the two values of arr?
Like x[arr[0], :, arr[1])

Comment: `x[:, arr[0], arr[1]]`

Comment: You mean `x[:, arr[:,0], arr[:,1]].T` @hpaulj ?

Comment: @yatu, his `arr` is a list.  My comment would work if it was `[[1,2], [1,2]]`.  With `[[1,1],[2,2]]` it needs some sort of 'transpose'.  Willem shows what I should have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is obtain these elements with

```
x[:,[1,2],[1,2]]
```

You perhaps are not capable to write this directly, since the `arr` can have an arbitrary number of elements. In that case we can unpack the result in a tuple:

```
x[(slice(None), *zip(*arr))]
```

Here the `zip(*arr)` will *transpose* the elements in `arr`, and we will then unpack the transpose as extra elements in the tuple. The `slice(None)` is basically what happens behind the curtains if you write a `:` in a subscript.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What if the array contains all the indices and we don't need a slice(None) or an integer before that? Im getting a compile time error that cannot use * expression over here.